# Azure management certificate error

Tags: azure

I created a certificate using "Makecert" and uploaded the certificate in my Azure account.I also used this certificate for calling the Azure Management REST APIs.But when I use the same certificate in another PC,certificate related error is thrown.So I again created the certificate in the new PC and the errors are resolved.

Do I have to create certificates for each machine and upload all them in the azure Site?Please let me whether we can resolve the problem with only a single certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumblede upon [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuremanagement/thread/6eed5275-cf8f-44a6-8d76-8a9ec7b443bb/) thread... If I'm right, it should work for you.

Note, that you will need to share the certificate on other machines to make this work.

Basically, after creating the certificate you need to install it into your certificate store, and export the certificate with its private key, then install that certificate on your other machines.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to create certificate on each machine. I believe the error is coming because you just copied the "*.cer" file from one computer to another and the private key was not exported. One way to solve this problem is to export the certificate with private keys (will create a pfx file), copy the pfx file on the 2nd computer and install the certificate there.That should do the trick. Give it a try.